# Php regular expression, url validation, following dots in domain name is valid?

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with validating group 2 which is the (sub)domain and extension.

My regex: `/^(http:[\/]{2})([\w\d\-\_\.]+)(\/(?:[\/\w\W]+)?)?$/`

Issue on: `([\w\d\-\_\.]+)`

Issue: http://www.....google....com/stuff is valid, I tried doing `[\w\d\-\_][(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)]+` but alas it doesn't work.

How can I make it so that if there's a `.` behind or a `.` in front of a `.` that the regex will return false.

https://regex101.com/r/fS9dG7/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this version of [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/fS9dG7/12):

```
^(http:[\/]{2})((?![^\/]*?\.{2}[^\/]*?)[\w\d\-\_\.]+)(\/(?:[\/\w]+)?)?$
```

The problem was with the `\W` (together with `\w` in the same character class) that matched everything, even a new line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
~^https?:/{2}(?!.*?\.\.)([\w\d.-]+)(/.*)?$~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fS9dG7/11)

btw in PHP you can also use `parse_url` function for parsing URLs.

`(?!.*?\.\.)` is a negative lookahead that will disallow 2 dots.